# JTable column widths only changing after two requests

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, preferredsize

In my application, I have a two column table which will be dynamically populated through the life of the program.  I have a method called `updateTableWidths` which, when called, does the following:

- makes the first column just as wide as it needs to be to fit cell contents
- makes the second column just as wide as it needs to be to fit cell contents
- if the entire table is wider than its container, enables a horizontal scrollbar
- otherwise, lets last column stretch to fill container

It seems to work great, but for some really strange reason it needs to be called **twice** (but only in some cases, i.e. when table widths are growing rather than shrinking).  The SSCCE below illustrates my dilemma.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TableResizeTest extends JComponent {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    private JTable table;
    private JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TableResizeTest window = new TableResizeTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    window.frame.requestFocusInWindow();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TableResizeTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setBounds(300, 300, 200, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Col_1", "Col_2"},0);

        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
        table.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        table.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        table.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setTableHeader(null);
        table.setEnabled(false);
        table.getColumnModel().setColumnMargin(0);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JButton btnFillTableShort = new JButton("Fill table short");
        btnFillTableShort.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.add(btnFillTableShort);

        JButton btnFillTableLong = new JButton("Fill table long");
        btnFillTableLong.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.add(btnFillTableLong);

        JButton btnUpdateTableWidths = new JButton("Update table widths");
        btnUpdateTableWidths.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.add(btnUpdateTableWidths);
        btnUpdateTableWidths.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                updateTableWidths();
            }
        });
        btnFillTableLong.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fillTableLong();
            }
        });
        btnFillTableShort.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fillTableShort();
            }
        });
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        scrollPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32767, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        scrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));

        frame.pack();
    }

    public void fillTableShort() {
        tableModel.setRowCount(0);
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"short", "short"});
    }

    public void fillTableLong() {
        tableModel.setRowCount(0);
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"looooooooooooooooooooong", "looooooooooooooooooooong"});
    }

    public void updateTableWidths() {
        int col_1_width = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, 0);
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, 0);
            col_1_width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, col_1_width);
        }
        col_1_width += table.getIntercellSpacing().width;
        col_1_width += 10;
        table.getColumn("Col_1").setMinWidth(col_1_width);
        table.getColumn("Col_1").setMaxWidth(col_1_width);
        System.out.println("col_1_width was set to " + col_1_width);

        int col_2_width = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, 1);
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, 1);
            col_2_width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, col_2_width);
        }
        col_2_width += table.getIntercellSpacing().width;
        int tableWidth = col_2_width + col_1_width;
        if (scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible()) {
            tableWidth += scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getWidth();
        }
        if (tableWidth > scrollPane.getWidth()) {
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            System.out.println("Auto resize was set to AUTO_RESIZE_OFF");
        } else {
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
            col_2_width = scrollPane.getWidth() + col_1_width;
            System.out.println("Auto resize was set to AUTO_RESIZE_LAST COLUMN");
        }
        table.getColumn("Col_2").setPreferredWidth(col_2_width);
        table.getColumn("Col_2").setMinWidth(col_2_width);
        System.out.println("col_2_width was set to " + col_2_width + "\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the sequence of steps you can follow to reproduce the behavior:

1) Launch the app

2) Click button "Fill table short"

[image]

3) Click button "Update table widths" (in this case only one click is needed)

[image]

4) Click button "Fill table long"

[image]

5) Click button "Update table widths" (first click)

[image]

6) Click button "Update table widths" (second click)

[image]

After the second click, it displays properly.  I have some debug info that prints to the console, and for both the first and second click, the method seems to be doing exactly the same thing:

```
col_1_width was set to 152
Auto resize was set to AUTO_RESIZE_OFF
col_2_width was set to 142
```

So it's not like there is some obvious difference happening the second time around as a result of something that was changed during the first run.  And as I mentioned earlier, this only happens when table columns have grown, rather than shrunk.

I am really stumped here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to specify the preferred size for the first column as well to work properly with the scroll. Try adding this line:

```
table.getColumn("Col_1").setPreferredWidth(col_1_width);
```

in the the block that handles `Col_1` calculations in `updateTableWidths` method. It solved the issue in the posted SSCCE.

***EDIT:***

There is a dependency on maxWidth and minWidth in `setPreferredWidth`. Below is the code for `setPreferredWidth`. So the order may matter.

```
public void setPreferredWidth(int preferredWidth) {
    int old = this.preferredWidth;
    this.preferredWidth = Math.min(Math.max(preferredWidth, minWidth), maxWidth);
    firePropertyChange("preferredWidth", old, this.preferredWidth);
}
```

Also exploring `setMaxWidth` indicates that it may set preferred width as well:

```
public void setMaxWidth(int maxWidth) {
    int old = this.maxWidth;
    this.maxWidth = Math.max(minWidth, maxWidth);
    if (width > this.maxWidth) {
        setWidth(this.maxWidth);
    }
    if (preferredWidth > this.maxWidth) {
        setPreferredWidth(this.maxWidth);
    }
    firePropertyChange("maxWidth", old, this.maxWidth);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, it does solve it, but as I mentioned above in @MadProgrammer's answer, it apparently matters that I put it **after** the min/max assignments.  I also have to move the `setPreferredSize` call for column 2 down by one line so it is below the `setMinimumSize` call for that one.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, I figured it might be something like that, but your eagerness to dive into source code faster than me (or at all) earns you the answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `TableColumn#setWidth` and/or `TableColumn#setPreferredWidth`

ie

```
table.getColumn("Col_1").setWidth(col_1_width);
table.getColumn("Col_1").setPreferredWidth(col_1_width);

//...///

table.getColumn("Col_2").setWidth(col_2_width);
table.getColumn("Col_2").setPreferredWidth(col_2_width);
```

Comment: Funny thing is, after I made my post I tried just that (`setPreferredWidth`, not `setWidth`), and it wasn't working.  But just now I played around more and realized I was setting `preferred` one line before `min` and `max`.  Moving that line to **after** min/max did the trick.  Weird that the **order** of those 3 lines makes a difference!  Similarly, I had to move the `setPreferredWidth` call for column 2 to just after the `setMinWidth` call.

Comment: Also, out of pure academic curiosity, I still have to wonder why it worked with no `preferred` call if the `min` and `max` calls were made twice.  Strange.

Comment: It probably has something to do with how the models are updated and the container hierarchy is invalidated. Personally, I'd use setWidth where possible, unless you absolutely want restricted width column s (ie they can't be resized at all)

Comment: Yeah, I do want the first column locked down completely.  Thanks for the info and suggestion though.